# Can a laptop with more RAM than it can handle can cause errors?

Tags: hardware-failure, memory-error

I'm having some trouble with my laptop. I'm using Windows 10. About seven months ago, I've changed my laptop's RAM from 2GB to 4GB and during this time everything was going well.

But recently, when I turn on my laptop out of the charger, the power light turns on, I can hear the fans of the laptop (with the sceen in black), but after 3 seconds it automatically shuts off. When I turn it on with the laptop in the charger, he does the same procedure, but after a while he turns on by itself and then shuts off. I believed that this process of turning on and off automatically was an infinite loop. However, if I wait about 10 minutes, the laptop can turn on and show the home screen.

I was finding this process of waiting 10 minutes to turn on the laptop exhausting, but at least I could use it. But while using, Blue Screens of Death began to appear, with error codes like **CRITICAL PROCESS DIED**, **SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION** and **UNEXPECTED STORE EXCEPTION**. At first, I thought it was virus, but I guess the virus can't affect the hardware. So researching, the only thing I found similar was the fact that the computer has a higher RAM than it can handle. After everything, my questions are:

- Is the RAM increasing the cause of these errors?
- Can I restrict the computer to use only 2 GB of RAM?
- In the worst case, will I have to buy a new RAM and install it?

Comment: There is also a possibility you may have a faulty RAM. Try running memtest?

Comment: Additionally to Darius' comment, consider to remove the new RAM to see if the problem disappears, then use process of elimination (swap in/swap out) to narrow down a possible faulty module.

Comment: Too much RAM is never a problem. But faulty RAM inmost likely the cause of something like this.

Comment: Too much RAM can be ruled out - if it can boot once, your chipset is fine with it always. Faulty RAM is very unlikely to cause a shutoff, depending on when the RAM was discovered faulty it would result in a BIOS beep, an unreliable boot or an UEFI system message. If your laptop is HP, the most likely cause is the infamous "dry caps" symptome, in this case you need a replacement system board or a solder job.

Comment: @EugenRieck: That's not true. Booting doesn't test the whole RAM capacity anymore, so the OS can seem to boot perfectly fine as long as it stays in the lower 2GB, but begin crashing in various ways as soon as it tries to access memory beyond the controller's capabilities.

Comment: (So while @JakeGould says "too much RAM is never a problem", I did learn the hard way that going over the documented maximum DIMM size is definitely a problem. In my case, the docs said "max 16GB total" but really meant "max 4GB per module", so using a 8GB module caused the system to instantly reset itself whenever it tried to access addresses above 0x100000000.)

Comment: @grawity: If the RAM passes the BIOS test, the System will not shut down - so why is my "unlikely to cause a shutoff" wrong? I am not talking about the OS starting to boot ans then failing - I am talking about the situation in the Question!

Comment: @grawity: A BSOD with too much RAM is a completely different pair of shoes - the bootloader did run successfully. This is not what is happening here.